# Adblock Plus blocks non advertising content of my site

Tags: html, css, adblock

Adblock firefox add-on blocks the main content of my home page - http://ad4you.eu

What should I do to prevent that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Not calling it `ad4you` would seem like a good starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change "id" and "class" names like "ad1", "ad2" to smth else

Can you specify what content affected by Adblock?